# Find the least nonnegative residue of $68^{105} \pmod{13}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I did a problem before this, which was finding the least nonnegative residue of $2^{204} \pmod{13}$. Because $2^{6} ≡ 1 \pmod{13}$, I said that $(2^{6})^{34}≡1^{34} \pmod{13}$, and so I concluded that $2^{204}≡1 \pmod{13}$. But for this one I can't find a way to break up $68^{105}$ so that it works out like that.

Comment: Well, you have $3^{12}\equiv 1\pmod {13}$ by Fermat's little theorem, so $68^{105}\equiv 3^{105}\equiv (3^{12})^8(3^{9})\equiv 1^83^9\equiv 3^9\pmod {13}$, and then you just square successively: $3^2\equiv 9, 3^4\equiv 81\equiv 3, 3^8\equiv 9\,\Rightarrow\, 3^9\equiv 3^8\cdot 3\equiv 9\cdot 3\equiv 27\equiv 1\pmod {13}$.

Comment: Or instead of using FLT (Fermat's little theorem) you can observe $3^3\equiv 27\equiv 1$, and $68^{105}\equiv 3^{105}\equiv (3^{3})^{35}\equiv 1^{35}\equiv 1\pmod {13}$, so this is solved analogously to the $2^{204}\bmod {13}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write out the first few powers, you will get:

$$68^1= 5\cdot 13+3\equiv 3\mod 13$$
$$68^2= (68^{1})^2\equiv 3^2\equiv 9\mod 13$$
$$68^3= 68^{1}\cdot 68^{2}\equiv 3\cdot 9\equiv 27\equiv 2\cdot 13+1\equiv1\mod 13$$

So we have:

$$68^{105}=(68^{3})^{35}\equiv 1\mod 13$$

Answer (score 2):

$\bmod {13}\!:\ 68^{105}\equiv 3^{105}\stackrel{\text{FLT}}\equiv 3^{105\pmod {12}}\equiv 3^{-3}\equiv \frac{1}{27}\equiv \frac{1}{1}\equiv 1$.